# How to include html tags when rendering the output in the browser

Tags: html

In HTML, all the tags are parsed and the document is generated. How do I prevent the browser, not to parse some tags or print them as such?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sample HTML</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="yellow">
        <h1>This is Heading in H1</h1>
        <p>This is a small paragraph with the <pre><code><p></code></pre> tag</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here the `<p>` tag must be printed, but it doesn't. How do I do that? And extending the code, how do I make it to print the whole html file?

Comment: It is not possible as native HTML, but you could always parse it with PHP, for example. You can, if you want, parse specific tags and convert the HTML to text (so you would use entity encoding, instead, check the answer below).

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava He's already using that tag.

Comment: then @Barmar you solution is correct.Sorry my mistake I haven't seen the code

Comment: To print the whole HTML file, simply serve it up as plain text (i.e. give it a MIME type of `text/plain`, for instance by changing the file extension to `.txt`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use entities for the `<` and `>` characters:

```
<p>This is a small paragraph with the <pre><code>&lt;p&gt;</code></pre> tag</p>
```

If you're generating the HTML code with PHP, you can use `htmlentities()` to replace special characters with their entities.

Comment: The easiest way is to do a google search for an online HTML encoder.   Paste in the HTML and it will be encoded for you.  Here's one: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Encode.aspx

Comment: Can someone please tell me why -1 for this question? :(

Comment: Only the person who downvotes can answer that. We can't read his mind.

Comment: @subhamsoni: I suppose because you don't seem to want a programming solution to your web question.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using xmp instead of pre?

```
<body bgcolor="yellow">
        <h1>This is Heading in H1</h1>
        <p>This is a small paragraph with the <xmp><p></xmp> tag</p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Your solution is good. But If I want the code to be inline what should I do?

Comment: Depending on if his target is to make a semantic website, this should be disregarded as XMP tag is invalid code and is **deprecated**.

Comment: @Socialz can you be more precise

Comment: @subhamsoni XMP was used in HTML 3.2 and earlier, but was then deprecated and it was preferred to use PRE tag instead. So if you use XMP, you will not pass any validators, and to be honest I think it is a small thing to work this out with JavaScript. (http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#xmp)

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for pointing that out Socialz. DId'nt realize it has been deprecated. @subham, if you want to use pre tag, you have to encode html tags, it should be &lt;p&gt;. Like Socialz, pointed out, you have other ways to do it, like jQuery.text(). Ex: jQuery("pre").text("<p>");

Comment: @Veeru It was deprecated fifteen years ago. How did you manage to miss that?